# Is this polynomial solvable? $\sum_{i=0}^{k} p_{i}x^{k-i}$

Tags: polynomials

I'm given $p_{0},...,p_{k} \in \mathbb{R}$ and I only know, that $p_{0}=-1$. We create a polynomial using these values like this :

$\sum_{i=0}^{k} p_{i}x^{k-i}$

Can I tell for sure, that no roots exist? I got class notes that said so, yet I don't see why not. Or do they mean, that we don't know for sure, that these roots exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you are looking for roots over the reals. If $k$ is odd, then you polynomial will have a root. This follows from the intermediate value theorem. In the general case, you can use Sturm's Theorem to count the number of real roots. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem#Applications